# Recursive counter in entiy class

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm

I have three tables - `categories`, `products`, and `category_product_mapper`.

Categories form a structure that looks like a tree, which means for example there's one big category with id 1, then sub categories like 3, 5, and 7, and each of those subcategories have their own children, so it's like `1 - 3 - [12, 51, 23]`, and `2 - 7 - [23, 44]`.

Each category that is a leaf contains many products. And each product contains a `popularity` column. What I want to achieve is to set popularity attribute in categories entity, and calculate it inside the getter method.

The first problem I see is that I'd have to use doctrine entity manager inside the categories entity, to get the corresponding products and popularity information. No idea how to do that.

And another problem is with recurrence. Categories table contains information if it's a leaf or not. If it is, I would just count all products inside this category. But if it's not a leaf, I would have to count all nested levels of products below this category. How would I do that?

So having an entity class:

```
class Categories {
  private $category_id;
  private $isLeaf;
  private $popularity; // popularity sum of all products in this category
  public function getPopularity() {
    if($this->isLeaf() == true)
    {
      // do something
    }
    else
    {
      // do something else
    }
  }
}

class Product {
  private $popularity;
}

class Category_Product_Mapper {
  private $product_id;
  private $category_id;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It would be much nicer if you could link `Categories` and `Product` entities via relationships. Can you do it? Did you mean to have `one-to-many` or `many-to-many` (more probable)?

Comment: I meant many-to-many of course. How could I do this, and what would it change?

Comment: I think that bidirectional `many-to-many` would suit here the most: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional Basically, you would add `products` member to `Categories` entity and vice-versa. This, however, does not change the fact that you would need fetch categories/products recursively, but the link between those two entities would make it somewhat easier.